# Could undefined variable be used in a java function?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am reading the [HashMap.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html). In line 917, the function *values()* used a variable *values*. However, I searched all the java file without finding some defined variable named *values*. How to explain this?

```
  916       public Collection<V> values() {
  917           Collection<V> vs = values;
  918           return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
  919       }
```

Comment: Have you looked in the file of the parent classes? Edit: never mind, I just did!

Comment: 1+: I never knew that the Java class code was online! I've gone through the src.zip file of course, but the online code is a little easier for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the HashMap's parent class, [AbstractMap](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractMap.java.html):

```
300       transient volatile Collection<V> values = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just missed the fact that a variable can be his parent's.

Comment: @EarthWorm: you're welcome, and thanks for showing me the online Java source code repository!

Comment: :Actually, there is another better online repository for java (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java). BTW, I always wonder why can someone asked my answer in just one minute? Are you always hooked on stackexchange.com to provide answers?

Comment: @EarthWorm: no, I'm not, but there are enough folks flitting in and out in that there's usually several folks available to answer questions.